# UIElement Screenshot UWP - C#

Tags: c#, bitmap, win-universal-app, screenshot

I search in web but I not found any solution to take a screenshot an UI element (in bitmap by example) in UWP - Universal Windows Platform.

Comment: Here is a official [XAML render to bitmap sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XAML-render-to-bitmap-dd4f549f), you can have a check. Although this sample is for Windows 8.1 Store app, but in UWP the implement is the same.

Comment: Isn't this what you want: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.rendertargetbitmap?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: @JayZuo-MSFT, Thanks. But object to return type of RenderTargetBitmap, but I need this image(screenshot) in bitmap format, because I really need to do  args.DragUI.SetContentFromBitmapImage(myBitmap); on DragStarting of an UI Element.
Thanks

Comment: `RenderTargetBItmap` can be converted to bitmap using `BitmapEncoder`

Comment: @Sidewinder94, Thanks.
In short, I cant capture image from UI Element and convert to BitmapImage?
Ty

Answer (score 3):

You may use Render XAML to bitmap 
Some Sample Code here:

```
    // Render to an image at the current system scale and retrieve pixel contents
    RenderTargetBitmap renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();
    await renderTargetBitmap.RenderAsync(RenderedGrid);
    var pixelBuffer = await renderTargetBitmap.GetPixelsAsync();

    var savePicker = new FileSavePicker();
    savePicker.DefaultFileExtension = ".png";
    savePicker.FileTypeChoices.Add(".png", new List<string> { ".png" });
    savePicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
    savePicker.SuggestedFileName = "snapshot.png";

    // Prompt the user to select a file
    var saveFile = await savePicker.PickSaveFileAsync();

    // Verify the user selected a file
    if (saveFile == null)
        return;

    // Encode the image to the selected file on disk
    using (var fileStream = await saveFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
    {
        var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.PngEncoderId, fileStream);

        encoder.SetPixelData(
            BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8,
            BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore,
            (uint)renderTargetBitmap.PixelWidth,
            (uint)renderTargetBitmap.PixelHeight,
            DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().LogicalDpi,
            DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().LogicalDpi,
            pixelBuffer.ToArray());

        await encoder.FlushAsync();
    }
```

**Sample Example**
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XAML-render-to-bitmap-dd4f549f

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/lighthouse/2013/10/17/capturing-snapshot-in-windows-8-1-store-app/